# Video event issue: User touching screen before time to play

Tags: html5-video

Hi this question is for anyone who may be able to show me how to resolve this user issue. I have a script that plays a video with the user able pause and resume on touch. This was easy enough to do and works fine. At a certain point the script pauses the video for the user for a set time so the user has time to read the information on the screen. The intent is for them to be able to to resume playing the video after reading the information. If the user waits long enough, the touch to resume works fine. But, because some users read faster than others it is obvious I need to detect the touch even when the video was paused by the script - this is the part I need help with. Currently, if the video is paused by the script and the user touches the screen before the set time for the pause expires, the play button will show but pressing it to play will not resume the script until that time expires. I presume I need a listener inside the function the script used to pause the video. I am not quite sure the best way to handle that. Here is a snippet of my approach so far:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function playPause() {
  var el = document.getElementById("playButton");
  if (myVideo.paused) {
    myVideo.play();
    el.className ="";
  } else {

    myVideo.pause();
    el.className = "playButton";
  }
}

myVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);


var pause42 = function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 42 && !myVideo.paused) {
        this.pause();

        // remove the event listener after you paused the playback
        this.removeEventListener("timeupdate",pause42);
    }
};
myVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", pause42);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

FYI problem solved. Posting the answer here if it helps others.

```
var pause42 = function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 15 && !myVideo.paused) {
      this.currentTime = 42;
        this.pause();

        // remove the event listener after you paused the playback
        this.removeEventListener("timeupdate",pause42);
    }
};
myVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", pause42);
```